# Replace color with another color for match only in TD

Tags: jquery

I need to replace background-color property in `td` only when it match the color that need to be replaced

```
<td style="background-color:#AEE0EC;">24</td>
<td style="background-color:#cE00Ef;">25</td>
<td style="background-color:#EEAABB;">26</td>
<td style="background-color:#CCCCC;">27</td>
<td style="background-color:#001122;">28</td>
```

Let us say i need to replace `#cE00Ef` in td only with `#FF0000`. how can i do this with jQUERY

Fiddle http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdPdwO

UPDATE: I used script from `sinisnake` this works in fiddle but my actual page has year calendar & when i run this script it doent work i event wrapped it around setTimeout function to make sure if may be running before the complete page download.

How can i make it work so that 24 March td background color can be remove or replaced with white background. Not sure why below script is not working

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('td').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('style').split(':')[1]==="#AEE0EC;") {
        $(this).css('background-color','#ffffff;');
    }
    });
}, 5000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/acsd5Lke/1/

Comment: FYI, the background colors in your fiddle are different from those in the code you posted.

Comment: css() will return rgb format, so, conversion, or string search/replace in style attribute...

Comment: That is only for example i need to know how can color be replace with another if it matches

Comment: @Learning, if color will be inside style attribute: https://jsfiddle.net/dwcus87g/1/, if not, you will get it in RGB format, so your search should be RGB, too, or you have to convert it to value you need....

Comment: @sinisake, thanks for the script it works in fiddle but doesnt work with actual page wher ei have multiple calendar control. I have updated my question i am not sure why it is not working.

Comment: Just curious, if you want to select the elements with bg color #ffff00, you can do `$("[style*='background-color:#ffff00']")` which will give the list of elements which has bg color set to #ffff00

Comment: I want to remove element backgroun in for march 24 with background color `#AEE0EC` updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/acsd5Lke/1/

Comment: @Learning - https://jsfiddle.net/acsd5Lke/4/ -have a look at my answer as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the elements with bg color #ffff00, you can do `$("[style*='background-color:#ffff00']")` which will give the list of elements which has bg color set to #ffff00

```js
function replaceColor(colorToBeReplaced, newColor) {
  var $elements = $("[style*='background-color:"+colorToBeReplaced+"']");        
  $elements.css("background-color",newColor);
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  //replaceColor("#001122","#E6E6E6");
  replaceColor("#001122","transparent"); //in case to remove the bg as OP suggested  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#AEE0EC;">24</td>
    <td style="background-color:#cE00Ef;">25</td>
    <td style="background-color:#EEAABB;">26</td>
    <td style="background-color:#CCCCC;">27</td>
    <td style="background-color:#001122;">28</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the td's and get the color using jquery .css() which will give you an RGB value for each vackground color. You can then pass that rgb value to a functionto convert it to hex values - note that I use a previous SO answer from @Erick Petrucelli for this conversion function. This can then be compared to the target value and swapped by setting the .css() background color.

This is a quick answer and sets the values as lowercase. I would suggest making this more robust and explicitly setting the values to lower or upper case, but it gets the job done.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tableTest td').each(function(){
    var originalColor= "#ce00ef";
    var replacementColor = "#ff0000";
    var tdColor = $(this).css('background-color');
    var convertedColor = convertColor(tdColor);
    if(convertedColor.trim() == originalColor){$(this).css('background-color', replacementColor)};
    
   })
  
  function convertColor(tdColor){
    var rgb = tdColor.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
      function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Original Table - check td with 25 in it</p>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#aee0ec;">24</td>
    <td style="background-color:#ce00ef;">25</td>
    <td style="background-color:#eeaabb;">26</td>
    <td style="background-color:#cccccc;">27</td>
    <td style="background-color:#001122;">28</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

<br/>
<p>Modified Table - check td with 25 in it</p>

<table id="tableTest">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#aee0ec;">24</td>
    <td style="background-color:#ce00ef;">25</td>
    <td style="background-color:#eeaabb;">26</td>
    <td style="background-color:#cccccc;">27</td>
    <td style="background-color:#001122;">28</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I have updated my script but it is not working as i have multiple table for calendar https://jsfiddle.net/bmw5eqcL/1/

Comment: note that you need to iterate over each td in each calendar - you seem to be just interating over each table. Also - are you importating the jquery library and wrapping hte function in a document ready() ?

Comment: Yes, i am using Knockout to get data for calendar & for this reason i am using SetTimeout function to make sure if function is not running before data is downlaoded. problem is that it seems to be a bug in teh code by developer as this color is not in database calendar control randonly adds it from somewhere